# Get a consistent date format from NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using NSDates as keys for an NSDictionary, but for key value coding, I need a string. Importantly, I need it to not change representation across OSes or locales. When I show it to users, I'll use NSDateFormatter, of course, but internally it must always be the same. What's the best way get a consistent format as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter and specify the time zone as GMT and the local as "en_US_POSIX".

From Apple's: [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a
>   locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results
>   regardless of both user and system preferences.

Another option is to convert a NSDate to a NSTimeInterval with a method such as timeIntervalSince1970 and then to a hexascii value to use as a key.  NSDate returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

Comment: It'd be easier and more effective to simply prefix the decimal representation of the time interval with “date_” than to convert it to hex. More effective because even hex numbers can start with decimal digits, and I'm not sure that will fly as a KVC key.